# Triple Integral help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I cannot figure out why I'm getting a negative value running NIntegrate to calculate my triple integral. Below is my code:

```
S = 40
p1 = 0.37
p2 = 0.43
p3 = .05
UND = 1 - (p1 + p2 + p3)
b1 = S*p1
b2 = S*p2
b3 = S*p3
b4 = S*UND
x1 = 48
x2 = 47
x3 = 4
x4 = 1

NIntegrate[(x^(x1 + b1 - 1))*(y^(x2 + b2 - 1))*(z^(x3 + b3 - 1))*((1 -
   x - y - z)^(x4 + b4 - 1)), {z, 0, 1}, {x, z, (1 - z)/2}, {y, 0, x}]
```

I want to triple integrate the function:

```
f(x,y,z) = (x^(x1 + b1 - 1))*(y^(x2 + b2 - 1))*(z^(x3 + b3 - 1))*((1 -x - y - z)^(x4 + b4 - 1))
```

I want to do the following:

S S S f(x,y,z)  dy dx dz

where:
y goes from 0 to x

x goes from z to (1-z)/2

z goes from 0 to 1

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Are you sure about the value of `cp` ?

Comment: @Valacar yes, that's fine. It isn't used in the integral anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Thanks for sharing your code in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). It would further help if you remove anything on it that is superfluous and provide a minimum working example, easier to read.  Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers. Finally, please clarify if you are you having a problem with the mathematics  or with Wolfram Mathematica programming.

Comment: Your x range switches direction part way through, is that what you expect?

Comment: @KraZug no, x shouldn't change direction... can you elaborate how that is happening?

Comment: z goes between 0 and 1 and you have x going from z to (1-z)/2. So when z=1/3, the range is zero, but after that it swaps direction and you have an integral int_a^b where a>b.

Comment: @KraZug oh thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KraZug points out:

```
Plot[{Callout[z, "z", {.9, Above}], 
  Callout[(1 - z)/2, "(1-z) / 2", {.1, Above}]}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Z", None}]
```

[image]

```
In[2]:= Reduce[(1-z)/2>z]
Out[2]= z<1/3
```

So for z>1/3, the second integration range reverses.